# React JS, ASP.Net core Web API handle Cors

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My Project is having 2 apps. A React JS based SPA app and a ASP.Net Core web API project. The issue is I'm getting error "Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin"

I went through the articles on the web on how to allow Cors on the Web API project. But my question is this. Based on the recommended way of fixing this, is to define the set of allowed origins. But since front end is a JS app, the API request will come from the client or user's machine. So I can not exactly define the origin.

Other option is allow for all origins. Will this be be best option for my scenario? Or is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: Whether react project is http when api is https? strict-origin doesn't allow *referrer* to be displayed in requests from https to http.

Answer (score 2):

A misunderstanding.

> But since front end is a JS app, the API request will come from the
> client or user's machine.

API requests will definitely come from the client or user's machine but via your server where is the React application hosted.

**So, your server is the origin.**

E.g: When you are in the development phase, your React application will be hosted in say `http://localhost:3000/`. This is the origin of the request.

Hence in the .Net Core project, CORS should be configured at `Startup.cs` as:

At `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

and at `Configure` method:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```